# Geoserver - Access is denied to preview style

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I am using Geoserver 2.10 and Tomcat 8.5.11. When I want edit style and preview it, geoserver give me following error:

> File failed to upload: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp\upload__73bb119_15a50da8e4e__7fff_00000219.tmp (Access is denied)

Can you tell me how can I fix it ?

Here is image of error:[image]

Comment: Do you have permission to write to that dir?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Try to edit a file in the folder

Comment: I do not have any fiels in this folder :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to be clear, the account running GeoServer does not have the rights to write in the temporary folder. Either change the account running GeoServer (actually, Tomcat), or make that folder writable by changing its permissions.

Comment: ok I solve it with with running "startup.bat" as administrator